# Excel Conditional Formatting Percentile Range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a list of 100 students each with different scores
I would like to highlight the cells according to the following table:

```
0th to 20th percentile: Green
20th to 40th percentile Blue
40th to 60th percentile Purple
60th to 80th percentile Yellow
80th to 100th percentile Red
```

Note: Percentile NOT score

Currently Excel only allows me to highlight the top x% and bottom x% of the students, nothing in between.

How do I do that?

It will be good if I can highlight both column A and B based on the values in column B

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start with your data area selected, `$A$2:$B$6` in your case. Then go to the ribbon and click **Conditional Formatting-->New Rule**, then **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**.

In the formula bar, type `=AND($B2>21,$B2<=40)` and then set the desired format of the cells.

[image]

Here's the important parts:

- You want to lock the "condition" to column B, so you use the `$B` value. Because you're applying the conditional format to a range of cells, Excel will change the row number from `2` to whatever row is being tested.
- Add your other formulas to the same range `$A$2:$B$6` in the same way for the other colors
- [This site](https://exceljet.net/conditional-formatting-with-formulas) is an excellent reference and can teach you much more about this type of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed the way you started but use 5 rules with increments. 
Steps:

1. create 5 different top/bottom percentage rules.
2. Set each rule with 20% increments.
3. Then put them in the correct order.
4. Set the flag in conditional formatting to stop evaluating other rules if true (for all five rules).

Example conditional formatting rules:

```
bottom 20% (green) & enable conditional flag "stop if true" 
top 20% (red) & enable conditional flag "stop if true" 
top 40% (yellow) & enable conditional flag "stop if true" 
top 60% (purple) & enable conditional flag "stop if true" 
top 80% (blue) & enable conditional flag "stop if true"
```

Also see image
[image: sample]